JUnit Test method invocation with CompletableFuture.supplyAsync
in my class i have i class-field, which i'am verfing, that the method of this class-field is invoked three times. Now i moved the logic to "CompletableFuture.sypplyAsync" approach and it does not work anymore:
My Test fails, and it says, that it will be not invoked, what i'am expecting.
My Class:
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.RuntimeService; 

public class StartProcessService {
    private final RuntimeService runtimeService;
   
    public void handleInExkassodatenRequest(MyRequest request) {
        request.getDaten().forEach(entity -> {
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> selectRequiredProcess(entity))
                    .thenAccept(caseId -> {
                        log.info("Case started ");
                    })
                    .exceptionally(err -> {
                        return null;
                    });
        });
    }

    private CompletableFuture<String> selectRequiredProcess(InExkassodaten entity) {
        startNewProcess(entity);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(entity.getCaseId());
    }

    private void startNewProcess(MyObject myObject) {
        ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService
                .createProcessInstanceByKey("MY_KEY")
                .setVariable("MY_VAR", myObject)
                .execute();
    }
}

and my old test-method looks like this:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class MyServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private StartProcessService startProcessService;

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private RuntimeService runtimeService;


        @Test
void startProcesses() {

    ProcessInstantiationBuilder processInstanceByKey = mock(ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.class);
    when(runtimeService.createProcessInstanceByKey(anyString())).thenReturn(processInstanceByKey);
    when(processInstanceByKey.setVariable(anyString(), any())).thenReturn(processInstanceByKey);
    when(processInstanceByKey.execute()).thenReturn(mock(ProcessInstance.class));

    startProcessService.handleInExkassodatenRequest(InExkassodatenFactory.createValidTestData());
    verify(runtimeService, times(3)).createProcessInstanceByKey(anyString());
}

previously checked whether runtimeService.createProcessInstanceByKey was called.
But with introduction of CompletableFutur.supplyAsync in fails and goes to the "exceptionally" with error:

Wanted but not invoked: runtimeService.createProcessInstanceByKey(
 );
-> at
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.StartProcessServiceTest.startProcesses(StartProcessServiceTest.java:52)

How do i need to redesign code my production or testcode to test it with CompleableFuture?

It does NOT go into the exceptionally block. It's just that the method has not been called yet. You run it asynchronously, which means there is no guarantee it will have run by the time you execute the next statement. It might have. It might only start executing 1 hour in the future, or 2, or only 10 seconds in the future. Why do you expect the code to already have executed?

supplyAsync does exactly what its name suggests: it runs the code asynchronously. It doesn't make any guarantees when the code block will be executed.
I see two obvious fixes:

supplyAsync has an overload which accepts an optional Executor argument. The default is to execute on the ForkJoinPool.commonPool, but you can pass any other executor. One possible executor value is Runnable::run which will simply execute the code directly, without dispatching it to a thread pool (so the code remains single-threaded). You can extend your class to have an executor field or property and in your test assign Runnable::run to this field.

Use Awaitility to re-run the assertion until a given timeout is reached. Something like await().untilAsserted(() -> verify(yourMock, times(3)).yourCall()).


I would suggest the first approach, because it removes the complexity of having multiple threads and keeps things simple.
